# Google Analtyics search and replace filter URI with Regex with an exception

Tags: regex, replace, filter, google-analytics, find

Currently our registration form tracks UTM and SEM codes, plus you get very long string with Social sign ins. I end up with roughly 4k enrollment variations, very hard to track outside of goals.

In order to better trouble shoot channels, I've created a separate view where I want to combine everything into just /enrollment while excluding thank you page. So i would have a list like this:

```
www.mysite/enrollment
www.mysite/enrollment/
www.mysite/enrollment/sem01
www.mysite/enrollment/sem02
www.mysite/enrollment?adsforefacebook
www.mysite/enrollment?utmforemail
www.mysite/enrollment/thank-you
```

I've tried using this filter which works in the goal section, but I can't get it to work under filters.

Find

```
www\.mysite\.com\/enrollment(?!/thank\-you)
```

Replace

```
www.mysite.com/enrollment
```

Theoretically, this should catch everything with enrollment except thank you pages and replace with the new string.

I've tried several variations that include .*, but no go.

Answer (score 0):

Oops. Nevermind, I think I figured it out right after I posted this. I don't think the normal find and replace works with exclusion patters and you have to use the Advanced filter... which worked exactly as expected with the above code.